# Why do I need to use unicode for a control character in a mapping using <expr> and a function?

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings

Let's say I've got the word `foo` in a file, I copy it in register `a` (`"ayiw`) and I define the following mapping:

```
inoremap <expr> <F3> "<C-r>a"
```

If I hit `F3` while in insert mode it will paste the content of register `a` (`foo`).

Now, let's say I define the following function, and the following mapping:

```
function! SomeFunction()
      return "<C-R>a"
endfunction

inoremap <expr> <F3> SomeFunction()
```

When I hit `F3`, instead of inserting the `a` register (`foo`), it inserts literally `<C-R>a`.

I found a solution, which involves changing the function and using the unicode for `<C-R>`.
I think `u12` is the unicode for the control character `<C-R>`, because when you insert it literally (`<C-V><C-R>`) and you hit `ga` on it, the output is `<^R>  18,  Hex 12,  Octal 022`.

So the following function and mapping works:

```
function! SomeFunction()
      return "\u12" . 'a'
endfunction

inoremap <expr> <F3> SomeFunction()
```

When I hit `F3` it inserts the content of the `a` register as expected.

But why do I have to use unicode when the control character is returned by a function instead of being directly passed as an argument to `:inoremap`?

**Edit**: After reading [Christian Brabandt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6073/4939)'s answer, I've realised that my solution was too complex.
As he has well explained, no need of unicode, a control character must simply be escaped in a string, so the proper way to write the function would be:

```
function! SomeFunction()
      return "\<C-R>a"
endfunction
```

And yet I'm still confused, if I type:

```
inoremap <expr> <F3> "<C-r>a"
```

It works as expected. So why do I need to escape `<C-r>` inside the function but not when it's directly passed as an argument to `:inoremap`?

For that, I think I have an explanation. The Ex commands which define a mapping like `:inoremap`, `:nnoremap`... don't need the control characters to be escaped. For example, you don't write:

```
nnoremap \<F3> :call SomeFunction\<cr>
```

but

```
nnoremap <F3> :call SomeFunction<cr>
```

Why? Probably because these commands are special, they already interpret correctly `<cr>` as a carriage return and not as 4 literal characters (same thing for `<F3>`).

So, going back to my previous function, why do I need to escape `<C-r>`?
Because, when I hit `<F3>`, `:inoremap` evaluates the right-hand-side of the mapping as a call to the function `SomeFunction()`... and that's it. It doesn't interpret anything after that, it just types the output literally.
The output of `SomeFunction()` is not interpreted by `:inoremap`, so this time you have to escape the control character so that Vim (not `:inoremap`) interprets `\<C-r>` as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to have Keys returned by mapping expressions, you have to escape them as mentioned in the help `:h expr-quote`. So your Function needs to return `"\<c-r>a"` (note the backslash), else you couldn't let the function return the string `"<c-r>a"`

Comment: Thank your for your answer. Just another question, if I type: `inoremap <expr> <F3> "<C-r>a"`, it works as expected. I don't have to escape `<C-r>`, why?

Comment: That is interesting and certainly unexpected. That might be a bug.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think it's a bug. If you look at the very bottom of `:h ins-special-special`, they give these 2 examples : `inoremap <expr> <Home> col('.') == match(getline('.'), '\S') + 1 ?
  \ repeat('<C-G>U<Left>', col('.') - 1) :
  \ (col('.') < match(getline('.'), '\S') ?
  \     repeat('<C-G>U<Right>', match(getline('.'), '\S') + 0) :
  \     repeat('<C-G>U<Left>', col('.') - 1 - match(getline('.'), '\S')))
 inoremap <expr> <End> repeat('<C-G>U<Right>', col('$') - col('.'))`. They don't escape `<C-G>`, neither `<Left>` nor `<Right>`.

Comment: Worse, they don't use double quotes, but single quotes (which prevents Vim from evaluating anything in the string).
My theory: they don't need to be escaped because the Ex commands which define mappings such as `:inoremap` don't need it,
they already know that `<CR>` for example means "carriage return", you don't need to write `\<cr>` in a mapping.
This is why I don't understand why I need to escape `<C-r>` when it comes from a function but not when it's on the command line.
But I like your answer, from now on, I will always use double quotes and escape to represent a control character.

Comment: i know the example very well. I am still not sure, whether this is a bug. I'll ask vim-dev

Comment: [I did](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/vim_dev/aRYJI5WWYFY/oEhvWUPaAwAJ) this is, because the map commands parse those keys directly.

Comment: Thank you! I think you're right, this should be documented because I've been confused by what happened for a long time.